# Why are the fragments communicating through the container Activity are called reusable?

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

I'm wondering why are the Fragments communicating through the container Activity are called reusable.

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html I know that:

> You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity
>   component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and
>   its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one
>   fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and
>   avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment.

Let's take an example; I have a `DateSetFragment` which contains two buttons; first button fires `TimePickerDialog` (FragmentDialog) which allows user to pick an hour and the second one `DatePickerDialog` (FragmentDialog) which allows user to pick a day. At the end gathered data should be sent back to the `DateSetFragment`.

According the: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html:

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

communication between fragments should be done via interfaces through the container activity. Given that I should send my collected data from both Fragment Dialogs to the container activity and then from the Activity back to the `DateSetFragment`. I don't see how this make my `DateSetFragment` reusable and modular in any way. Doing so I have to implement fragment interfaces and some crucial logic in my container Activity which makes it connected with it.

The question is; Is it wrong in this situation if Fragment Dialogs will communicate directly with the `DateSetFragment` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "modular" because those interfaces are well defined and explicitly implemented by the hosting activity.

Anywhere you drop that fragment in, if the activity implements the callback interface defined by the fragment events the activity can choose what to do depending on what environment the fragment is attached in.

Example,

```
DatePickerFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface DatePickerFragmentEventListener { 
        public void onDateSelected(DateTime dt);
    }
}



Activity1 extends Activity implements DatePickerFragmentEventListener {

    DatePickerFragment mDatePickerFragment;
    OtherFragment mFragment2;

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(DateTime dt) {
        mFragment2.setSomeViewsText(dt.toString());
    }

}


Activity2 extends Activity implements DatePickerFragmentEventListener {

    DatePickerFragment mDatePickerFragment;

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(DateTime dt) {
        SharedPrefClient c = SharedPrefClient.getInstance();

        c.setExpirationDateTime(dt);
    }

}
```

I have a dateTimePickerFragment (or whatever), in one activity I have 2 fragments, when you change the date on the picker I want to update the other fragment's text view to display that date. In another activity I might use that exact same callback to write the chosen date to SharedPreferences.

The point is that the Fragment is a contained piece of UI interaction, and certain events it will notify the enclosing Activity of what just happened to it, so that the activity dictates that the result of an action on the fragment does to either other fragment or the application itself. There is no reason to implement a custom fragment for each and every situation.